# React-Redux TypeScript Errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Tryign to implement TypeScript with React/Redux and I'm running into some issues with my Types.

I have these types:

```
export interface IAuthState {
  isSignedIn: Boolean | null;
  userId: string | null;
}

export interface IStream {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  userId: string;
}

export interface IStreamState {
  streams: { [index: string]: IStream };
}
```

Then I have two components:

```
interface IStreamsProps {
  fetchStreams: () => void;
  streams: IStreamState;
  currentUserId: String | null;
  isSignedIn: Boolean | null;
  auth: IAuthState;
}

class StreamsList extends Component<IStreamsProps, IAppState> {
   // Error: The Property Map does not exist on type IStreamState
   renderList() {
       return this.props.streams.map((stream: IStream) => (// CODE)
   }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppState) => {
  return {
    streams: Object.values(state.streams),
    currentUserId: state.auth.userId,
    isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchStreams }
)(StreamsList);
```

Then I have another similar component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppState, ownProps: HomeProps) => {
  return {
    //Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'IStreamState'
    stream: state.streams[ownProps.match.params.id]
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(StreamEdit);
```

How do I solve these two errors:

Error 1: The Property Map does not exist on type IStreamState

Error 2: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'IStreamState'

Comment: what is your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly defined `IStreamState`. Look closely. You've defined it as an object

```js
export interface IStreamState {
  streams: { [index: string]: IStream }[];
}
// equivalent declaration using type:
export type IStreamState = { 
  streams: { [index: string]: IStream }[]
}
```

I'm sure you mean to type it as just an array, as so:

```
export type IStreamState = { [index: string]: IStream }[]
```

EDIT:
While not directly related to your question, you need to be careful with your types. I noticed you used `IAppState` in two different places. The class declarations are for props and *local* state. `IAppState` appears to be for your redux store.

```
// the second generic argument is for `this.state`
class StreamsList extends Component<IStreamsProps, IAppState> {
```

EDIT2:
Defining both arguments in a class is optional. If you leave the second one out, it defaults to `{}` for you.

It's impossible to be 100% sure as to why you're having that issue in your `mapStateToProps`, because I don't know what `IAppState` looks like. Just go double back and confirm your typing for `state.streams` is exactly what you expect.

Comment: Oh actually, you're close, It should be an object that looks like this `{id: {IStream}, id: {IStream}}`

Comment: It's your app, so I'm not sure what the data structure was. It just seemed logical, based on the code, that your intention was to define `streams` as an array. That being said, with this context/information, are you able to solve this yourself?

Comment: Yea this helps, I changed the Interface of IStreamProps to `streams: IStreamState[]`. This solved the error I was having with `.map`. Still looking into the second error. Saw your edit as well, will take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your edit, I changed the signature to this `class StreamsList extends Component<IStreamsProps, {}>` since I'm not using local state. Good to know, I didn't realize this. Still figuring this stuff out.

Comment: Updated for a bit more context on your 2nd issue

Comment: I solved it this way: `const streamId: keyof IStreamState = ownProps.match.params.id; return {
    stream: state.streams[streamId]
  };`

But I would have preferred to do it in the interface.